# Use XSLT to filter source XML to destination XML

Tags: xml, xslt

Due to a production issue a bunch of data was corrupted. The good news is that I have all the data in an XML file which happens to be in the same format as the input to submit data changes. The problem I have is one record takes a while to process. My "clean master" has >20,000 records, and only 530 have been corrupted. I have a key field to identify the record I want to include in my destination. How can I include in an XSLT to output a node only if it is in a list I specify? I do not care if I hard-code the list in the XSLT.

```
<recordSet>
  <record>
    <key>123</key>
    <val1>abc</val1>
    <val2>def</val2>
   </record>
  <record>
    <key>456</key>
    <val1>hij</val1>
    <val2>klm</val2>
   </record>
  <record>
    <key>789</key>
    <val1>nop</val1>
    <val2>qrs</val2>
   </record>
 </recordSet>
```

Let's say I only want records with key 123 and key 789.
Thank you.

Comment: Which version of XSLT?

Comment: 1 or 2, as this will most likely only be run in a tool like Altova (manually) I have more flexibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I do not care if I hard-code the list in the XSLT.

Here's how you can do this efficiently and elegantly in XSLT 1.0:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="keys">
    <key>123</key>
    <key>789</key>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:key name="record" match="record" use="key" />

<xsl:template match="/recordSet">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="key('record', exsl:node-set($keys)/key)"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In XSLT 2.0 this can be reduced to:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="keys">
    <key>123</key>
    <key>789</key>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:key name="record" match="record" use="key" />

<xsl:template match="/recordSet">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="key('record', $keys/key)"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```